# Combining multiple asset data indices into one in Elasticsearch - is it possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I am working within a solution that pulls IT asset data from multiple indices depending on the customer's environment. What I would like to do it combine all of these indices into one enriched index which contains all of the data for that asset to create one "Asset Record" instead of having disparate data in multiple indices.

The problem goes something like this:
Source A: Zeek - provides 5 tuple "netflow" type data like IP addresses, ports and protocols.
Source B: Optional - provides detailed information incl. IP addresses, MAC, installed software, open ports, etc. for *all* Operating Systems
Source C: Optional - provides detailed information incl. IP addresses, MAC, installed software, open ports, etc. for *all* Operating Systems
Source D: Provides detailed information but only for Windows machines

My goal is to build an asset tree and then a topology viewer using ONE combined index that matches all of these separate data sources based on the noted IP address and creates one record per each asset.

Would I be best to look at using an Ingest Pipeline and an enrich processer? Or should I look at using something external to export the data, combine it elsewhere, and ship it back to ES in another index?

Thanks so much!

I have not tried anything yet, just doing the research.